# A difficulty in understanding the indices in the matrix interpretation of the product of two representation.

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products, tensors

I have a difficulty the indices in the two lines above the line starting with "Hence, $X$ transforms according to ..." , could anyone explain for me how the indices are located?

Also I do not understand from where the dual sign representation on $S_{f}(g)`$ came, could anyone explain this for me please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=(a_{ij})$, $B=(b_{ij})$ and $X=(x_{ij})$, then the $ij$-component of $AXB$ is
$$
\sum_{k,\ell}a_{ik}x_{kl}b_{\ell j}
$$
The formula appearing above is
$$
\sum_{k,\ell}a_{ik}x_{kl}b_{j \ell}
$$
which is the $ij$-component of $AXB^t$. The line beginning "Hence, $X$ transforms $\ldots$" simply states this.

Comment: what about the second question of the OP?

Comment: I think the OP is asking why the $a_{ki}$ becomes $a_{ik}$  and why the$x_{ij}$ becomes $x_{kl}$ and why $b_{lj}$ becomes $b_{jl}$  ..... which may be you did not answer..... if I understand correctly.

Comment: yes I think this is exactly what I meant@hopefully

Comment: That is simply a global relabelling of the indices (note $e_k\otimes f_\ell$ becomes $e_i\otimes f_j$).